# Выбор Ftp сервера

Tags: ftp, linux

Всем привет!

Подскажите фтп сервер, в котором бы можно было разграничить, возможные операции для каждого пользователя?

Например, админ - может выполнять все возможные операции, а пользователь, может только загружать новые файлы, но не удалять или изменять уже имеющиеся?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте proftpd, пользуюсь им. Хотя под ваши требования подойдет практически любой нормальный сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов простого администрирования сервера (также на proftpd) система zentyal, полностью готовое решение для "ленивого" админа.